# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xb0' in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, unicode, urllib, python-unicode

I am trying to download an Image from a link that contains special character like this:
`imageUrl = 'https://www.residentadvisor.net/images/labels/3000°records.jpg'`

```
request_=urllib.request.Request(imageUrl,None,headers) #The assembled request
print(request_)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request_) #store the response
```

but when trying to download I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xb0' in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Because the `Traceback` was to big to add please find it at this url:

[for Traceback click here](https://codeshare.io/2BV8mO)

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-d0b0a8f766c9> in <module>()
    135             request_=urllib.request.Request(imageUrl,None,headers) #The assembled request
    136             print(request_)
--> 137             response = urllib.request.urlopen(request_) #store the response
    138 #create a new file and write the image

    /Users/-/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
221     else:
222         opener = _opener
--> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
224 
225 def install_opener(opener):

/Users/-/anaconda/ lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
524             req = meth(req)
525 
--> 526         response = self._open(req, data)
527 
528         # post-process response

/Users/-/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _open(self, req, data)
542         protocol = req.type
543         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
--> 544                                   '_open', req)
545         if result:
546             return result

/Users/-/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
502         for handler in handlers:
503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 504             result = func(*args)
505             if result is not None:
506                 return result

/Users/-/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in https_open(self, req)
1359         def https_open(self, req):
1360             return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
-> 1361                 context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
1362 
1363         https_request = AbstractHTTPHandler.do_request_

/Users/-/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
1316             try:
1317                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
-> 1318                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
1319             except OSError as err: # timeout error
1320                 raise URLError(err)

/Users/-/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
1237                 encode_chunked=False):
1238         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1239         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
1240 
1241     def _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked):

/Users/-/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
1248             skips['skip_accept_encoding'] = 1
1249 
-> 1250         self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
1251 
1252         # chunked encoding will happen if HTTP/1.1 is used and either

/Users/-/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in putrequest(self, method, url, skip_host, skip_accept_encoding)
1115 
1116         # Non-ASCII characters should have been eliminated earlier
-> 1117         self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
1118 
1119         if self._http_vsn == 11:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xb0' in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Why do you say the traceback is too big? Copy/Paste should work just fine. I'm not going to click on a random internet link just to see essential information about your question.

Comment: because I can't publish the question in the current form with all the traceback ... s/o tells me to add more text since it seems to be only code if I format the traceback

Comment: i could add it as an image if you want ?

Comment: Go ahead and add the text without formatting, and someone will come along and format it for you. Stupid SO and their attempts to mandate content quality that backfire far too often.

Comment: now getting 'post appears to contain code that is not properly formated ...', will try to do it in a different way

Comment: @MarkRansom somehow it worked :) ... i added the traceback

Comment: Wow, I've never used IPython - it includes a lot more context in the traceback than I'm used to. I'd try using a Unicode string in the call to `urlopen` as suggested by a deleted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`urllib.request` expects a properly url escaped url.

In this case, the properly escaped url is:

```
imageUrl = 'https://www.residentadvisor.net/images/labels/3000%C2%B0records.jpg'
```

If you're dealing with potentially poorly encoded urls, one library which helps you encode them properly is [yelp_uri.encoding.recode_uri](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp_uri/blob/v2.0.0/yelp_uri/encoding.py#L64-L72).  Full disclosure: I have contributed to this library.

I used the following code to get the properly encoded url:

```
from yelp_uri.encoding import recode_uri
imageUrl = recode_uri(imageUrl)
```

Comment: thank you for the disclosure and the library ... works like a charm ;)